# "command not found" when connect qt with matlab

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, qt, mat

I got

> matlab: Command not found.

when I try to use qt to call matlab to plot by using the following standard command

```
 { 
 double z[num];
 ...
 Engine* eg;
 eg = engOpen(NULL);
 mxArray* z_array = mxCreateDoubleMatrix_700(num,1,mxREAL);
 double *pz = mxGetPr(z_array);

 for(int i =0;i<num; i++)
 {
 pz[i] = z[i];
 }

 engPutVariable(eg,"z",z_array);
 engEvalString(eg,"testPlot");
 engClose(eg);   
 }
```

and I have already created the testPlot.m file

```
plot(z);
grid on;
```

For connection between qt and matlab, I just include the followings in the .pro file (by some tutorials I do not understand too well)

> INCLUDEPATH +=/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/extern/include
>
> LIBS += -L/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -leng -lmex

Do I miss something to include? Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem, really thanks.

Comment: Do you have MATLAB on your system PATH?

Comment: What do you mean system PATH? I am newbie, really sorry.

Comment: Options here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/27326

Comment: If my understanding is right I add to .pro like below  `INCLUDEPATH +=/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/extern/include\
          /Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab\
          /Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/mex`

Comment: It's not an issue with your .pro file. It's something that you have to configure on your system. Try running `export PATH=/Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin:$PATH` in the terminal before launching your app

Comment: I tried,  command not found, again. but still thanks

Comment: How are you launching your app?

Comment: Just click the alias in my application

Comment: Ok what about running the following line in a terminal: `launchctl setenv PATH /Applications/Matlab/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Then you may have to run `osascript -e 'tell app "Dock" to quit'` http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications

Comment: Still the same. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you open a terminal, what happens when you type `matlab`?

Comment: It shows "-bash: matlab: command not found".